# How can I paginate with APA7 format?

Tags: page-numbering, apa-style

I need to paginate on the top right of the thesis because that's what APA 7 Format asks for. My problem is that I can't paginate the pages with titles like Chapter 1, 2, etc with arabics, but I can paginate the rest of the pages that don't have a title. Same with the index, I can't paginate on the top right of the page with romans.

I'm using \fancyhead[R] in order to put the number of the page on the top right of the page.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt, twopage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber, uniquename=allfull ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}
\cite


\marginsize{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}
\graphicspath{ {figuras/} }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\title{ELECCIÓN DE UN MÉTODO DE PROCESAMIENTO DE IMÁGENES DE
RAYOS X, PARA EL SOPORTE DEL DIAGNÓSTICO DE LESIONES
TRAUMATOLÓGICAS DE LA ESTRUCTURA PÉLVICA} %Cambiar según el título de su tesis
\author{Nombre del Estudiante}

\makeatletter 
\let\newtitle\@title
\let\newauthor\@author
\makeatother
\fancyhead[R]
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Content}}
\fancyhead[R]
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables index}}
\fancyhead[R]
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\tablename}{tables}}
\begin{document}
\include{portada} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Índice de figuras}} 
\listoffigures 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Índice de tablas}} 
\listoftables 

\include{resumen}
\include{introduccion} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Capitulo1} 
\include{Capitulo2} 

\include{bibliografia} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Did You forget the MWE???

Comment: Welcome. The behaviour you say you want is the default. Even if you use `fancyhdr`, you still get a different style for the first page of chapters etc. So you are using some code you've not shown which is using the same page style (probably) on those pages or (less likely) you've redefined that page style to do the same as well. If you post a minimal example which compiles to reproduce the problem, we can help.

Comment: Please don't vote to close questions before OPs have had a chance to respond to requests for improvement. This is neither welcoming nor productive.

Comment: the fancyhdr documentation has a section about this (Redefining page style plain).

Comment: You are right, now  edited the question with the code I used